# Infinitesimally small area $(dx)^2$ as a point

Tags: calculus, infinitesimals

I read in one book that infinitesimally small area $(dx)^2$ is a point. But point has no length in general sense. It's dimensionless.

[image]

How is it possible? And how to understand it?

Thanks.

Comment: Infinitesimals have long been a grey area where handwaving arguments abound. It can be made (and has been) more formal, but usually that is not worth the cost. If you want to formalize the informal reasoning made here, use $\varepsilon - \delta$, or limits, kinds of arguments.

Comment: This is a case where a poor explanation makes things less understandable because it manipulates objects that are not clearly defined. For example "Now let PQ be infinitesimal": too bad the author doesn't define what it means!

Comment: This is a good question and should not be closed.  It would be helpful to know where the quotation is coming from.

Comment: I agree with @Jean-ArmandMoroni - the amount of advanced math the complex ideas needed for nonstandard analysis just doesn't seem worth it when we have a perfectly good framework in $\epsilon-\delta$ methods and limits. At least for me as an applied math person.

Comment: Agree — @mike_bb — this is a perfectly good question.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments note, this is very muddled language. There is a way to work with things like $dx$ somewhat like we work with numbers, but only if you put in the work to understand [nonstandard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis), which was developed to make the vague notion of "infinitesimal" rigorous.

You'll see this kind of argument a lot in Physics courses or numerical analysis, where we use the heuristic that $dx > (dx)^2 > (dx)^3$ etc as a ways of properly "cancelling out" powers of differential signs when we do formal symbolic manipulation of things like power series. But it's a heuristic.

I'm not sure what book this is but based on the typesetting it looks older. There are plenty of modern texts in calculus that don't stray into this territory and instead focus on the usual limit-based arguments.

If you want a rigorous introduction to single variable calculus, I'd recommend
[Ross' Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1461462703)

Comment: I suggest you actually learn something about modern infinitesimals before making deprecating comments at their expense.

Comment: @MikhailKatz - if I said something incorrect I’m happy to correct. Indeed I’m not a specialist in nonstandard analysis but I think I’m echoing the same sentiment as you: the source text seems outdated, there are rigorous ways to work with infinitesimals that have been developed that avoid fuzzy reasoning.

Comment: Well, the second paragraph of your *answer* has nothing to do with your summary above.  You may want to consider deleting it.

Comment: @MikhailKatz ok — can move this more to the comments vs here to keep the main answer clearer.

Comment: @MikhailKatz yes — agree. Nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: Good, if you think the question is OK you could consider upvoting it since anti-infinitesimal folks are beginning to downvote it.

Comment: @MikhailKatz already did - the downvotes made no sense

Answer (score 1):

Would you be so kind as to identify the source for this passage?  It seems to be a reprint of a 19th century calculus or analysis textbook.  Indeed, the explanation that the author provides is insufficient.  It does not explain anything to claim that "$dx^2$ is a point".  A proper explanation involves the [standard part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_part_function#Definition).

Comment: Bartholomew Price "A Treatise on Infinitesimal Calculus: Differential calculus. 1857" (https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Treatise_on_Infinitesimal_Calculus_Dif.html?id=yU9LAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y , page 40-41)

Comment: That explains it, then: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartholomew_Price @Mike_bb